# Difficulty with PHP $_GET

Tags: php, get

I'm having difficulty with a homework assignment using PHP.

```
    <?php
        if (!isset($_GET['board'])){
            echo "Board value not set";
        }else{
        $position = filter_input(INPUT_GET ,'board');
        $squares = str_split($postion);

    echo $squares[0].'<br/>';
    echo $squares[1].'<br/>';
    echo $squares[2].'<br/>';
    echo $squares[3].'<br/>';
    echo $squares[4].'<br/>';
    echo $squares[5].'<br/>';
    echo $squares[6].'<br/>';
    echo $squares[7].'<br/>';
    echo $squares[8] .'<br/>';

    if (winner('x',$squares)){
        echo 'You win.';
    }elseif(winner('o', $squares)){
        echo 'I win.';
    }else{
        echo 'No winner yet.';
    }
}
function winner($token, $squares){
    $won = false;
    if(($squares[0] === $token) && ($squares[1] === $token) && ($squares[2] === $token)){
        $won = true;
    }elseif(($squares[0] === $token) &&($squares[3] === $token) && ($squares[6] === $token)){
        $won = true;
    }elseif(($squares[0] === $token) &&($squares[4] === $token) && ($squares[8] === $token)){
        $won = true;
    }elseif(($squares[1] === $token) &&($squares[4] === $token) && ($squares[7] === $token)){
        $won = true;
    }elseif(($squares[2] === $token) &&($squares[4] === $token) && ($squares[6] === $token)){
        $won = true;
    }elseif(($squares[2] === $token) &&($squares[5] === $token) && ($squares[8] === $token)){
        $won = true;
    }elseif(($squares[3] === $token) &&($squares[4] === $token) && ($squares[5] === $token)){
        $won = true;
    }elseif(($squares[6] === $token) &&($squares[7] === $token) && ($squares[8] === $token)){
        $won = true;
    }
    return $won;
}
?>
```

This is the PHP I'm using. My problem comes when I enter the url and follow it with ?board=xxx---ooo the str_split method isn't storing anything in the squares[]. It recognizes that there is 'board' because the !isset gets triggered but it doesn't pass the characters through so my echo prints 8 returns, and my winner function can't evaluate properly.

I feel like I'm missing something minor here and just can't see it.

Comment: Where is your form, is your `form method` set to get ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo, change :

```
$squares = str_split($postion);
```

To :

```
$squares = str_split($position);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please change the following line:

```
$position = filter_input(INPUT_GET ,'board');
```

with

```
$position = $_GET['board'];
```

and care about your variable name spelling.

You missed an 'i' in your naming.

It could resolve your problem, I think.

Comment: Without any filter specified as the third parameter for the filter_input there's no difference between the two. The answer is the one given in the other answer before, as you also edited it later. So the first part is just misleading.

Comment: First solution will ensure that the data is gotten correctly from $_GET. without this try, any debugging try may faults.
As the second solution